# Ubuntu 12.10 Gtk Themes Not Fully Applied

Tags: gnome

I try to apply several themes downloaded from this list:

> http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/a-list-of-best-15-ubuntu-1204-themes.html

But the themes looked so weird when applied, especially the icon and menu bar.
It seemed that the theme are not fully applied (I assume).
Because when I browse into one of the theme folder (example SLAVE), there is an **icons** folder, but no changes on icons when it was applied

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VmnE.png) is the preview:

[image]

I hope it can be solved soon. It's frustrating to have buggy desktop appearance.

Comment: themes are for 12.04, search for 12.10 theme.

Comment: I'll try 12.10 theme

Comment: @Web-E: looks like what you said is right. When I tried to `gnome-shell --replace`, gtk showed many error about theme syntax. Installed several compatible themes, works fine.

Answer (score 3):

GTK3 and its various theme engines have gone through some rapid changes recently, especially between 3.4 and 3.6. It might just be the case that the specification for themes has changed between minor versions, and the ones you're using are out-of-date already.

Here are some roundups of GTK3 themese compatible with 3.6 (ie. Ubuntu 12.10):

- [8 GTK 3.6 Compatible themes available in PPAs for Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/8-gtk-36-compatible-themes-available-in.html)
- [17 GTK themes for GNOME 3.6](http://worldofgnome.org/17-gtk-themes-for-gnome-3-6/)

Or you can just trawl [gnome-look.org](http://www.gnome-look.org) for themes that say they're 3.6 compatible.